# Data rendering in grid

Tags: extjs

I am developing a application using ExtJs, and I have a problem. I have one grid which is have 2 column (date 1, date 2), however when I insert the data, the date 1 and date 2 appears normally and automatically in grid, but when I refresh the page all dates appears: '31/12/1969', the timestamp is returned correctly (1346284800000), can anyone provide a insight ??

```
{
    header: 'Date 1',
    dataIndex: 'date1',
    flex : 0.3,
    renderer : function(value, cell, model, index) {
        data = new Date();
        data.setTime(value); 
        return Ext.util.Format.date(data, 'd/m/Y');
    }
}, {
    header: 'Date 2',
    dataIndex: 'date2',
    flex : 0.3,
    renderer : function(value, cell, model, index) {
        data = new Date();
        data.setTime(value);
        return Ext.util.Format.date(data, 'd/m/Y');
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you're trying to display Unix timestamp in the grid. Try this renderer:

```
renderer: function(value) {
    var date = Ext.Date.parse(value, 'U');

    return Ext.Date.format(date, 'd/m/Y');
}
```

Comment: The 'value' in 'renderer' function is coming null, but in  my response server it is coming the timestamp, I dont know what is happening.

Comment: Most probably it means you've misconfigured your Model. Or haven't configured it at all, even more likely. Please post your Store configuration.